# How to store multiple data with array in laravel mvc?

Tags: arrays, laravel

> I am working on mvc I don't know much about OOP concepts. I am using 
>   laravel for my first demo project.  I have 1 form with `add more` 
>   button.  onclick `add more` button next same form will open and both 
>   div's value should be store in table. I want to store data in
>   seperate rows. If I go through this way it stores nothing in table.How
>   can we store all data?

**Form :**

```
<div class="form-group box" id="fieldList">
  {!! Form::label('address',trans('messages.address'),[])!!}
  {!! Form::input('text','address_line_1',(isset($company) ? $company->address_line_1 : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.address_line_1')])!!}
                    <br />
  {!! Form::input('text','address_line_2',(isset($company) ? $company->address_line_2 : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.address_line_2')])!!}
                    <br />
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-5">
  {!! Form::input('text','city',(isset($company) ? $company->city : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.city')])!!}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
 {!! Form::input('text','state',(isset($company) ? $company->state : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.state')])!!}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
 {!! Form::input('text','zipcode',(isset($company) ? $company->zipcode : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.zipcode')])!!}
</div>                      
</div>                  
                    <br />
 {!! Form::select('country_id', config('country'),(isset($company) ? $company->country_id : ''),['class'=>'form-control show-tick','title'=>trans('messages.country')])!!}
                    <br />

 {!! Form::label('gstn',trans('messages.gstn'),[])!!}
 {!! Form::input('text','gstn',(isset($company) ? $company->gstn : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.gstn')])!!}
</div>
</div>
 {{ getCustomFields('company-form',$custom_field_values) }}
 {!! Form::submit(isset($buttonText) ? $buttonText : trans('messages.save'),['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) !!}
<input class="button-add btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Another Address">
```

**Script to clone above div:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.button-add').click(function(){

        $('.box:first').clone().insertAfter(".box:last");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function() {
        $(this).closest(".box").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**store method:**

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $request, Company $company, Companyaddress $companyaddress){   

        if(!Entrust::can('create-company'))
            return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.permission_denied'), 'status' => 'error']);

        $data = $request->all();
        $company->fill($data)->save();
        $companyaddress->fill($data)->save();
        storeCustomField($this->form,$company->id, $data);

        $this->logActivity(['module' => 'company_address','module_id' => $company->id,'activity' => 'added']);

        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.company').' '.trans('messages.added'), 'status' => 'success']);
    }
```

**Model :**

```
class Companyaddress extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [
                            'companies_id',
                            'address_line_1[]',
                            'address_line_2[]',
                            'city[]',
                            'state[]',
                            'zipcode[]',
                            'country_id[]',
                            'gstn[]'                            
                        ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'company_address';
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you are asking here,  can you elaborate?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nbpyyuwu/ my form is same like this link. suppose i have 2-3 clone box. i want to store all data in table how to handle this

Comment: Seems like your "name" attribute of form inputs is not array, make sure that it is rendered as <input name="article[]" type="text">

Comment: that's what i cant undestand how to to store multiple data with array. i used for loop in my controller now but it storing only last clone of form